# QtCreator on linux: 32-bits vs. 64-bits

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

My laptop is 64-bits, so when I start to use Qt, I chose 64-bit QtCreator.
Now I'm facing a problem, I wish that the executable files I generated are runnnable on 32-bit linux system.

Can I set QtCreator to generate 32-bit executable files? So that I can decide I want to generate 32-bit ones or 64-bit ones.

I don't want to install another 32-bit QtCreator ><.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to install a 32-bit Qt, at least.  You shouldn't need to install a 32-bit Qt Creator, though.

Once you install a 32-bit Qt, you should be able to add that version to Qt Creator and have it work without much trouble.  You may need to force Creator to use the `linux-g++-32` mkspec while compiling.  If you build the 32-bit Qt yourself, you can do this by configuring with `-platform linux-g++-32`.  If you install it from a package, hopefully the package builder has already done this.

Comment: Thank you :)

Now I've installed 32-bit Qt, but I'm not very familiar with QtCreator setting. From the QtCreator and the "Qt Version" option, I can only specify the location of "qmake". How can I do configuration and switch between 32 and 64-bits?

Answer (score 3):

I've figure out how to generate 32-bit codes.

from the "project" tab in QtCreator:
Build Settings
Build Steps
QMake -> show detail

put following arguments in "Additional arguments":

```
-spec linux-g++-32 -r
```

Comment: That's right, you must have installed a 32 bit Qt beforehand, though.

Also, one thing I forgot before: some 64 bit distributions of Linux simply don't support compiling 32 bit binaries (they don't ship any gcc with a working `-m32` flag).

Comment: what `-r` flag means?